# How to format date in Powerautomate when Email to .CSV

Tags: export-to-csv, powerbi-desktop, email-attachments, power-automate-desktop

Im looking for Powerbi/Powerautomate help.  I have created a flow to export a table in Powerbi by email in .csv  format.

But the date is always in UTC=  "2024-01-22T14:14:34.000Z".    Here is my flow,  can someone tell me how I could format to short date  "MM-DD-YYYY".  What action, where to insert...etc?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UivIQ.png)

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance

Tried inserting Compose action, adding formatdate, but outcome did not work.

Comment: Update your question with screen snip of steps `Apply to each` and `Create CSV table` expanded so we can see where the date is being outputted. The expression should be `formatDateTime({the date column}', 'MM-dd-yyyy') `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `formatDateTime([ASSIGNED_DATE], 'MM-dd-yyyy')` function inside your 'Append to array variable' action.

Replace the PowerBI variable 'ASSIGNED DATE' with an [expression](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/use-expressions-in-actions/) to allow you to use the `formatDateTime()` function and insert the 'ASSIGNED DATE' PowerBI variable as the first parameter of the function.

Microsoft have some really useful documentation for date time values and how to add the expression to the flow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/date-time-values).